# !important не работает в Safari

Tags: css, safari

Подскажите пожалуйста. в Safari 5+ на `!important` показывает ошибку. и не работает. как это можно исправить?

Comment: перед `!important` должно идти валидное css свойство и значение

Comment: @Grundy там всё валидное. указание ширины. `width: calc(100% - 20px) !important;`

Comment: так а что за ошибка?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko показывает желтый знак возле свойства и это свойство не работает.

Comment: @Tsyklop, и тут ты ошибаешься: [can i use calc?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: @Grundy как тогда быть?

Comment: @Tsyklop, очевидно - не используй calc

Comment: @Grundy а он нужен.

Comment: @Tsyklop, неа, раньше и без него обходились, это раз. Для 6, 7 версии может заработать с префиксом `-webkit`, это два. Для пятой - без вариантов - нужно убирать calc

Comment: @Grundy я поставил на ПК его. а на ПК этой функции нет. Придётся искать телефон.

Comment: на телефоне версия для iOS - она может отличаться от десктопной, но calc там работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46020/discussion-between-grundy-and-tsyklop).

Answer (score -1):

`!important` поддерживается в `Safari 3+`. 
Также `calc` [поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) всеми современными браузерами.

Попробуйте использовать `calc` в другом виде:

`width: calc(~"100% - 20px") !important;`

Comment: в вопросе речь идет о конкретных версиях конкретного браузера, поэтому некорректно говорить в ответе _поддерживается всеми современными браузерами_

Comment: calc не поддерживается в safari 5.1